# Loop through a object attribute while in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My API call gets a response like this

```
  {
  products: {
    product0: {
      id: 'F103_SURFACELAPTOP_15',
      quantity: 47,
      description: 'Surface Laptop 15 Zoll'
    },
     product1: {
      id: 'F101_MACBOOKPRO_13',
      quantity: 10,
      description: 'Macbook Pro 13 Zoll'
    }
  },
  salesOrderId: '9000002080'
}
```

It can contain 1 - n products. I'm trying to print the response in a table

This is what I got which is working but it will just show the first product. However I need to loop through products and show every product

```
  {value.map((item, i) =>
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{i + 1}</td>
              <td>{item.salesOrderId}</td>
              <td>{item.products['product' + i].id}</td>
            </tr>
          )
```

This is how I tried to loop through it but with no success

```
   {value.map((item, i) =>
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{i + 1}</td>
                  <td>{item.salesOrderId}</td>
                  {item.products['product' + i].map((product, i) =>
                   <td key={i}> {product.i.id} </td>)}
                  <td>{item.products['product' + i].id}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that API should rethink the format of its output...

Answer (score 1):

Because the `value` is **Object** not a **Array**

so use like this

```
{Object.values(value).map((item, i) =>
```

instead of

```
{value.map((item, i) =>
```

use loop on this format

```
{Object.values(value).map((item, i) =>
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{i + 1}</td>
                  <td>{item.salesOrderId}</td>
                  {Object.values(item.products).map((product,ind) =>
                   <td key={ind}> {product.id} </td>)}
                  <td>{item.products['product' + i].id}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through object attributes you can use `Object.values(value)` if you need only values, and `Object.entries(value)` if you need both: keys and values. Both this functions return arrays on which function `map` is available